# Does Hyper-V bare metal require Windows Server 2008 R2 - 2012?

Tags: hyper-v, bare-metal

Is there a bare metal Hyper-V that I can install via Windows 7 - 10?  I've read but I don't understand how I get bare metal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Bare metal" means you're installing the hypervisor directly on the machine, no other OSs involved (other than the OSs running in the VMs).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor#Classification):

> **Type-1, native or bare-metal hypervisors**
>
> These hypervisors run directly on the host's hardware to control the
>   hardware and to manage guest operating systems. For this reason, they
>   are sometimes called bare metal hypervisors.

[Hyper-V Server 2012 R2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-hyper-v-server-2012-r2?i=1) is an "unlimited evaluation" version that you can download and use for free.

Comment: You can boot directly to Hyper-V VMs in Windows 8+.  Hyper-V does not run on Windows 7

Comment: Despite all the downvotes, you answered.  Thank you for that.

Answer (score 2):

So to answer your question, no, it does not. You can install Hyper-V directly on your hardware with no intermediate Server OS layer.

However, your other question:

> Is there a bare metal Hyper-V that I can install via Windows 7 - 10?

So this is worded a little weird, but here is the answer along with a tidbit that I just learned recently. You can enable Hyper-V on Windows 8, 8.1, Windows 10 (read this for the [requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/quick_start/walkthrough_compatibility)). This is not really what is meant by bare-metal, but what is really interesting about Hyper-V is that when you enable it and restart your computer, Hyper-V inserts itself underneath the OS layer, thereby, in a way, becoming a bare-metal hypervisor. In other words, in either scenario-- installing Hyper-V via the OS interface or installing Hyper-V as a standalone product-- Hyper-V gains direct access to hardware layer, thereby becoming a type-1 hypervisor.

You can read about that more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768520(v=bts.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks.  Can you make it boot to a different OS if you install Windows 10 and do Hyper-V like you describe?  Like autoboot to a Linux guest?

Comment: No; minimally, no entry is made to your bootloader when you create a guest VM, so it won't be a bootable option.